# mule http endpoint post data

Tags: mule, mule-studio

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"   contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" path="getDetails" />
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
<logger message=" Logging ...... #[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

i invoke thru chrome rest client

**http://localhost:8081/getDetails**

METHOD : post

below is json data

{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "xyz",
    "lastName": "abc",
    "address":"xy"

}

whatever json data i passed , i just want to print for processing . but
**In logging it shows null payload**

any suggesstion are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I tested your scenario with the following :-

```
 <flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
      <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"   contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" path="getDetails" />
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message=" Logging ...... #[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

And I got it in the log as bellow :-
[image]

Comment: Check the answer .. are you sure you are not getting it in log .. I tried the same scenario and I got it in log ..  Just check if you are getting the Data from your Rest client and hitting the correct url –

Answer (score 0):

You have probably posted in the same question in another thread too.
Please read comments in [mule post json data to mule endpoint url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445886/mule-post-json-data-to-mule-endpoint-url/29462989)

Answer (score 0):

After http:inBound you need to convert it to json using object to string transformer