# mule post json data to mule endpoint url

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"   contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" path="getDetails" /> 
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
<logger message=" Logging ...... #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger level="INFO" message=" Logging mule.......#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="Logging demo .......... #[payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

i invoke thru chrome rest client

http://localhost:8081/getDetails

METHOD : post

below is json data

```
{
  "id": "1", "firstName": "xyz", "lastName": "abc", "address":"xy"
}
```

whatever json data i passed , i just want to print for processing . but In logging it shows null payload

any correct solutions  are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but I tried your scenario by following :-

```
<flow name="Flow1" doc:name="Flow1">
      <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"   contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" path="getDetails" /> 
      <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
      <logger message=" Logging ...... #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <logger level="INFO" message=" Logging mule.......#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
      <logger level="INFO" message="Logging demo .......... #[payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

And you can see I am able to log the values :-

[image]

Comment: Just check you are hitting right url from your Rest client .. It's working fine in my case

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct. As Anirban pointed out, you may be making mistake while invoking the service. I tried invoking this service using postman plugin in Chrome and selected post with raw XML and it worked fine. Please try with postman and confirm if you still have the same issue.